# What's the intuition behind re-parameterization in the Dickey-Fuller test?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

In text books and lecture slides, people often explain that the normal t-test of, say, the AR(1) parameter in the Dickey-Fuller test does not follow the usual distribution. It also explain that after having re-parameterized the CLT still doesn't hold and so we need to use the special DF disitrbutions.

So the usual disitributions neither hold before or after the re-parameterization. Why do we then need it? Is there a reason we don't calculate the disitrbution before the re-parameterization and simply test via these? I, understand, that there must be a reason, but I am interested in what it is.